# Only one instance of a scriptmanager can exist on a page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I design an ASP.NET web usercontrol and with a maskeditor and scriptmanager, I always get an object reference not set to an instance of an object exception at runtime.

Stacktrace is:

[InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.]
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnInit(EventArgs e) +384613
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378

What causes this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Where are you declaring the ScriptManager - in the UserControl, the Page that host the control, or in a MasterPage?

I'd recommend (if you can - the main caveat is .NET 3.5 installed on the server) defining the ScriptManager in the MasterPage (or page level if you're not using MasterPages), and then using a [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) in your user control:

> Enables nested components such as content pages and user controls to add script and service references to pages when a ScriptManager control is already defined in a parent element.

**Edit to add:**

If you can't use the ScriptManagerProxy, then either take a look at the [ToolkitScriptManager](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Walkthrough/OtherNeatStuff.aspx) from the AJAX control toolkit - it gives you a lot of the features of the .NET 3.5 ScriptManager without having to use 3.5, including the .GetCurrent method:

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

if (null != scriptManager) {
  // Create a new ToolkitScriptManager and add it to the page.
}
```

Alternatively you could perform that lookup yourself, by iterating through the Page's control collection looking for a ScriptManager instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Telerik control then Script manager can't work .

**We can use either Telerik control  or ScriptManager**

Answer (score -1):

I think your error is more related with "**Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page**".

Check if you have more than one ScriptManager on your page

Comment: Apologies, yea the current except is actually exactly that but if I taker the scriptmanager out, I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're having problems with master and content pages as @Zaph comments below?